# Extracting all tweets on a topic from yesterday using Python's Tweepy?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, tweepy, social-media

It seems that Python API allows people can dig back tweets tweeted a couple days ago. Since I don't need to stream tweets instantaneously and yet I want to collect all tweets on a particular topic (ie: fast car) for a period, I think running a python script collecting all the tweets on a topic from "yesterday" will do. The following codes does something like that, but I can only get a pre-specified amount (ie: 200), I can bumped up the number to very large (ie: 50,000) but is there a better way to capture ALL the tweets on a topic the day before?

```
import tweepy
import time

ckey = ""
csecret = ""
atoken = ""
asecret = ""

OAUTH_KEYS = {'consumer_key':ckey, 'consumer_secret':csecret,
    'access_token_key':atoken, 'access_token_secret':asecret}
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_key'], OAUTH_KEYS['consumer_secret'])
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Extract the first "xxx" tweets related to "fast car"
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='fast-car', since='2014-09-14', until='2014-09-15').items(200): # need to figure out how to extract all tweets in the previous day
    if tweet.geo != None:
        print "////////////////////////////////"
        print "Tweet created:", tweet.created_at
        print ""
```

Answer (score -1):

To attempt answering this question, I could set the number of item retrieved to be a hypothetically huge number, for example items(999999999), and once the script extract all tweets from the previous day, it will stop automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Just don't put any number as a parameter and it will return them all.

Comment: when you don't provide .items(200) at the end you get an error 'Cursor' object is not iterable